# How to implement generic interface as a non-generic class Java

Tags: java, class, generics, interface, implementation

I want to realise a java class, based on generic interface. I got error class GroupDaoImpl must be declared as abstract or implement abstract method update()

What i do wrong?

**My interface**

```
public interface EntitiesDao<T> {
    void add(List<?> entity);
    List<T> getList();
    void update(T entity);
    T findById(Long entityId);
    void delete(Long entityId);
}
```

**My class**

```
@Repository
public class GroupDaoImpl implements EntitiesDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public void add(Group group) {
        em.persist(group);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Group> getGroupsList() {
        CriteriaQuery<Group> criteriaQuery = em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(Group.class);
        Root<Group> root = criteriaQuery.from(Group.class);
        return em.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Group group) {
        em.merge(group);
    }

    @Override
    public Group findById(Long groupId) {
        Group group = em.find(Group.class, groupId);
        if (group == null) {
            throw new EntityNotFoundException("Группа с ID = " + groupId + " не найдена");
        }
        return group;
    }

    //удаляет сущность по id
    @Override
    public void delete(Long groupId) {
        Group group = em.find(Group.class, groupId);
        if (group != null) em.remove(group);
        else throw new EntityNotFoundException("Группа с ID = " + groupId + " не найдена");
    }

    public void addStudent(Student student){}

}
```

Comment: `implements EntitiesDao<Group>` ?

Comment: Make it `class GroupDaoImpl implements EntitiesDao<Group>` and implement all the methods from the interface.

Comment: I got the same error with method add. I should change only class signature?

Comment: Since you are using wildcard - method from this interface will be hardly useful. Why not make `add` method in your interface at least `void add(List<T> entity);`? Also you are passing a single instance of `Group` to your `add` method - not a `List`.

Comment: the add method from `EntitiesDao` uses a `List<T>`  so you should implement your interface correctly and add the `implements EnitiesDao<Group>` in your class declaration

Answer (score 0):

How your interface is using generic, you must implement using the wildcards:

```
public class GroupDaoImpl implements EntitiesDao<Group> {}
```

And for the method add you must implements as declared in the interface, you are declaring as a **List** so you must implement as a **List**:

```
void add(List<?> entity);
```

Implementation:

```
@Override
public void add(List<Group> group) {

}
```